# How to add the View below the TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

How should I add the `View` (`ImageView`) below the `UITableView`?

and the View can be scrolled with `UITableView`

Because my `TableItem` can be expanded

Comment: Add the view as in UItableview footer in last section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the UITableViewDelegate method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and return the desired view (e.g. a UILabel with the text you'd like in the footer) for the appropriate section of the table.

***Somewhat like below.***

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *sampleView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    sampleView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    sampleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return sampleView;
}
```

and include UITableViewDelegate protocol.

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
```